# How to generate all possible strings, with all ascii chars, to a certain length

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I've been struggling a bit today, trying to make a function, that can generate all possible strings, with all possible ascii chars, up to a certain length.

So basically, first a single char, from 0-255. Then two where I get AA, then AB, then AC... etc (but using ascii char codes, to get all possible values in each spot).
Does that make sense?

I guess I suck at recursion, because every attempt I make, either gets way too complicated for myself to figure it out, or ends up only increasing the last position in my string.

I'm completely stuck here and loosing all overview of what I'm doing.
I've tried googling to no avail, usually ending up in the same articles that doesn't quite seem to be the same problem.

I'll be happy with any examples, it doesn't have to be javascript.

Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Why would you start at `AA` not `A\0` if you really wanted all 256 codes? And notice that ASCII goes from 0 to 127 only. Or do you actually only want the 26 uppercase alphabet letters?

Comment: I do actually want to start from chr(0), I just figured AA would be an easier example to write.

Comment: OK, if you want to go from `0` to `255` it would be better to talk about "byte sequences" not "ascii strings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator, that recursively builds up the string and yields up the results to the caller:

```
  function* chars() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
      yield String.fromCharCode(i);
  }

 function* combinations(length, previous = "") {
   if(length <= 0) {
      yield previous;
      return;
   }

   for(const char of chars())
      yield* combinations(length - 1, previous + char);
}
```

That way you can get all combinations as:

```
  const result = [...combinations(5)];
```

Note that `255 ** n` is a lot, so you might want to consume the combinations one after another:

```
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

  (async function() {
     for(const combo of combinations(5)) {
       console.log(combo);
       await timer(1);
     }
 })();
```

Comment: I'd recommend to do the recursive base case condition outside of the `for` loop…

Comment: Notice that promises are on microtasks, so `await tick()` (which is mostly equivalent to `await;`) still blocks the event loop. Better do `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));` every few thousand combos.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. So pretty. Thank you. There is one thing I don't really understand, maybe it is because of the generator. At any point, if I take combo.length, for any purpose, it will be the max set length (5 in the example) and not the length of the actual string. Why is that?

Comment: @nicolai isn't that the length of the actual resulting string?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I suck at recursion

You seem to be looking for a recursive solution.

Might this pseudocode solve your problem?

```
F(n)
    if (n == 1)
        return asciiCharacters

    suffixes = F(n - 1)

    for each character of asciiCharacters
        for each suffix of suffixes
            results.push(character + suffix)

    return results
```

where `asciiCharacters` is an array of ASCII characters.