# How do I get the length of the current string, from a yield*

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I posted this question: [How to generate all possible strings, with all ascii chars, to a certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693201/how-to-generate-all-possible-strings-with-all-ascii-chars-to-a-certain-length)

The accepted answer has some pretty slick code, but I am having some issues understanding it.
In essence, if I ask the length of the string coming out, it is always the same size as the max length it can output.

I'm guessing it's the yield* that really causes me some issues.
When reading about yield*, it does say that it takes the final value into account.
So, I've changed the following code, to highlight my issue.

```
(async function() {
   for(const combo of combinations(5)) {
     console.log(combo.length + "\t" + combo);
     await timer(1);
   }
})();
```

The output is as follows:

```
5      !
5      "
5      #
5      $
5      %
5      &
5      '
5      (
5      )
5      *
5      +
5      ,
5      -
5      .
5      /
5      0
5      1
5      2
5      3
5      4
5      5
5      6
5      7
5      8
5      9
5      :
5      ;
```

Even when the string is only 1 character, it still claims it is 5.
So, how do I get the length of the ACTUAL value, coming out of the generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* getting the length of the actual value. There are two things going on here:

First, the code they gave you only outputs strings of length 5 (or whatever number was passed in), not strings of ascending length as you asked for. Ie, they gave you code that doesn't match your requirements. If you want to keep the generator approach, here's some code that will output strings of all lengths 1-5, though i'm not sure its quite in the order you want:

```
function* combinations(length, previous = "") {
  for(const char of chars())
    yield previous + char;

  if (length > 1) {
    for (const char of chars())
      yield* combinations(length - 1, previous + char)
  }
}
```

Second, the reason the strings *look* like they're shorter than 5 characters is that there are unprintable characters preceding printable characters, and you only see the printable ones. For example, the first character that the algorithm will work with is `String.fromCharCode(0)`, and that character is unprintable.

```js
const unprintable = String.fromCharCode(0);
console.log(unprintable);
console.log(JSON.stringify(unprintable));

const longer = unprintable + '!'
console.log(longer);
console.log(JSON.stringify(longer));
console.log(longer.length);
```

Comment: This is why you should when in doubt print the representation of the string `console.log(JSON.stringify('\x00'));` rather than the string.